# Grab DateTime variable from CodeBehind to javascript in ASPX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datetime

I currently have a variable called `ClassStartDate`, so this variable is a `DateTime`. I want to grab this value and pass it to `jquery datepicker` to set min date. Is there a way to do it? I tried but I can't.

Here's what I've tried

ASPX.CS

```
public DateTime courseStartDate;

foreach (DataRow row in retrieveBAL.retrieveBatchByProjCode(ddlProjCode.SelectedValue).Tables[0].Rows)
{
       courseStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["courseStartDate"]);
}
```

ASPX

```
$('#<%= tbStartDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    minDate: '<%= courseStartDate %>'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#<%= tbStartDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
                        changeMonth: true,
                        minDate: '<%= courseStartDate.ToString("dd-MM-yy") %>'
    });
```

Comment: Superb! Merci Beaucoup!